# filter array after merging keys of one array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create filtered **array 3** using **array 1** and **array 2**.

**ARRAY 1**

```
Array ( 
          [title] => value 
          [title2] => value2 
          [title3] => value3
      )
```

**ARRAY 2**

```
Array ( 
          [0] => Array ( [id] => 20 [title2] => value2 [otherColumn1] => otherValue1)
          [1] => Array ( [id] => 21 [title4] => value4 [otherColumn3] => otherValue3)
      )
```

Desired Result after applying the **intersection** method:

**ARRAY 3**

```
Array ( [title2] => value2 )
```

So far I am unable to achieve the result because **array 1 and 2** have non-matching structures. I have tried different techniques but I am unable compare them due to structure differences.

```
   if (!empty($data1['array2'][0])) {

                foreach ($data1['array2'] as $key) {

//                    $filtered= array_intersect($array1,$key);
                    //  print_r($key);
                }
                // $filtered= array_intersect($array1,$data1['array2']);// if i use $data1['array2'][0] it filters fine but just one row

                //    print_r($filtered);
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Difference between `array1` and `array2` is sort of `[title] => value`. How do you expect getting `[title2] => value2`?

Comment: thankyou @Hashem Qolami i was using the wrong function . but still the problem is still there how can i get its intersection when the structures are different ?

Comment: Both arrays contain title2 and title3, so why does your filtered array only have title2?

Comment: ugh sorry it was a typo, fixed it . yes only title 2 is common in both arrays now...

Comment: So, you want to intersect on all keys which start with "`title`" + their values? Why do you have differently named keys? Can't they/shouldn't they all just be "`title`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the arrays:

```
$arr = array('title' => 'value', 'title2' => 'value2', 'title3' => 'value3');
$arr2 = array (
        0 => array ( 'id' => '20', 'title2' => 'value2', 'otherColumn1' => 'otherValue1'),
        1 => array ( 'id' => '21', 'title4' => 'value4', 'otherColumn3' => 'otherValue3'));
```

You can get your filtered array with this:

```
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr2);
$filtered = array_intersect($arr, $merged);
```

If you want to intersect just according to the keys you can use this instead:

```
$filtered = array_intersect_key($arr, $merged);
```

Comment: +1 Possibly needs `array_intersect_assoc` or `array_intersect_key` though.

Comment: @deceze - I'm not sure why. My result had the key still intact if that's what you mean.

Comment: No, I mean that the OP seems to want to intersect on keys + values, or just keys. Only intersecting on values may lead to false positives here.

Answer (score -1):

you can remove structural difference in the following way

```
$arr1 = array (
        0 => array('title' => 'value', 'title2' => 'value2', 'title3' => 'value3'));
$arr2 = array (
        0 => array ( 'id' => '20', 'title2' => 'value2', 'otherColumn1' => 'otherValue1'),
        1 => array ( 'id' => '21', 'title4' => 'value4', 'otherColumn3' => 'otherValue3'));
```